# Mobile (Android) Browser: Remove border from read only input fields

Tags: android, input, field, readonly

First post here, but I've been trolling for ages and always find the answers here helpful, so thanks to the community for the previous help :)

My issue is this:  I'm building a mobile site for my company's website using basic form fields.  I'm calculating the totals on an order form by using read only input fields.  The issue is that in my Android browser (and possibly other browsers, I haven't fully tested yet), the read only fields display a border even though I've tried to remove it - see the summary section at the bottom of the form below.

Here is the order form:  https://m.eyemagic.net/cc-order.html

Maybe you can provide some assistance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are using an `edittext`as your read only input field. If so to make it similar to the given web page, just make the `android:background` transparent as:

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtBoxId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" />
```

Hope it is helpful.. :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Where is this EditText specified?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to appear as simple text, then use < span > and style appropriately. However if you want to stick to <  input type="text" .../ > then make sure it is not editable and not focusable too.

```
       <input type="text" disabled="disabled" taborder="-1" ...>
```

this will prevent android from drawing the focus border around the control too.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this...and while it does reduce the visibility of the border, the borders are still displayed on my phone.  I'd like them to disappear completely for this input field.

Also, how would I display this with the span property?  I tried span name="shtotal1" but that displays nothing.

Comment: Use html tag < span > if the data inside is not to be submitted in a form. Make sure to specify an id attribute, such that you were able to access it via var spanObject = document.getElementById(id);   then   spanObject.innerHtml = "the text you want to appear here" will do the trick.